# Html input pattern attribut

Tags: html, input, attributes

Hello i'm trying to make a pattern of vehicule's license plate with this pattern
`123-AB-1234` in my html input .
3numbers-2upper-4numbers.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following regex pattern-

```
^[0-9]{3}-[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{4}?$
```

You may get rid of the hyphens in between like, `^[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}?$` if they are not needed.
You can test any regex in general on https://regex101.com/

Comment: @FahedSelmi , glad I could help.